# How to submit form with captcha

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to complete captcha on Amazon website. But when submitting form getting `<Response [503]>`. Captcha is being solved correctly. What might be the issue?
This is how my code looks like

```
def solve_captcha(self, content):
        captcha_img = content.find("form").find("img")['src']
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(captcha_img, "captcha.png")

        with open('captcha.png', 'rb') as captcha_file:
            captcha = self.api.solve(captcha_file)

        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/errors/validateCaptcha'
        payload = {'field-keywords' : str(captcha.await_result())}

        session = requests.Session()
        s = session.post(url, data=payload, headers={"Referer": "https://www.amazon.com/"}, proxies=self.proxy)
        return s
```

Comment: Does `captcha.await_result` output the same value both times you call it?

Comment: yes the same, even if removing print it gives same Response

Comment: not sure if this will work but try replacing `data=payload` with `json=payload`